# Pointer to structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
typedef struct stack{
 int size;
 int array[30];
}STACK;

int p;
STACK *W;
```

What is the difference between  `(*W).array` and `(*W).array[0]`?
How do I get an int pointer to the first element in the array if I have `W` and `p`?

Comment: You do know that you can use `W->array` instead of that crude `(*W).array`?

Comment: Yes, I know. But can I use W->array[0] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between (*W).array and (*W).array[0]

`W->array` is an array and `W->array[0]` is an element.

> How do I get an int pointer to the first element in the array if I
>   have W and p?

Don't know what you want to do with `p` but **`W->array` already decays to a pointer to the first element**. However, if you want, say, the fifth element:

```
int *p = &W->array[4];
```

Comment: `int *p = &W->array[4];` ... what about `int *p = W->array + 4;` ?

Comment: @LihO Sure, it's the same thing :-)

Comment: @LihO: That's indeed identical, though some may consider it less obvious (the former alternatives says literally: "take the address of the thing at index 4").

Answer (score 0):

Either `(W->array)` or `&(W->array[0])`

There is *no* difference in the address of an array and the address of the first element of the array

Comment: The adress *may* be the same, but the type (and the size, and hence the steps taken during pointer arithmetic - compare `&(W->array) + 1` with `&(W->array[0]) + 1`) is different. Arrays do decay to pointers to their first element, but not in all contexts  - address-of is one exception.

Comment: @delnan:Not sure I follow you.Do you disagree that if I have `pp=&z[0]` then `pp` now points to `z[0]`?Also `pp=z` is the same thing.So you are saying that there is a difference with `pp=z`?What I am saying is that these are the same

Comment: Both `int *pp = &z[0];` and `int *pp = z;` work and make `pp` point to the first element of the array (assuming `z` is an int array), but `int *pp = &z` (which is what your answer is using) will not.

Comment: @denlan:Oops!I see what you are talking about!I will correct this